# Set Custom Recipient for PayPal Payment in new Android SDK

Tags: android, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to integrate PayPal into my Android App and using the new Android SDK to do it (as I understand MPL is no longer good practice).

I got it working, but can't seem to find how it's possible to setup a custom recipient email (as was possible with MPL, at least according to the documentation).

Does anyone has any idea on how this can be done?

Thanks, 
-Lior